# tikz-cd `shorten` in combination with `squiggly`

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-cd, decorations

I want to draw a shortened squiggly arrow, like the following:

[image: short squiggly arrow]

However, when I use `shorten` in combination with `squiggly`, I get a strange effect, where the shortened segment is drawn both as squiggly and as a straight line (rather than not drawn at all):

[image: bad squiggly arrow]

The code is:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \bullet && \bullet
    \arrow[shorten <=10pt, shorten >=10pt, squiggly, from=1-1, to=1-3]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to shorten the decoration itself in addition to the path. Found an old reference to this in http://pgf-and-tikz.10981.n7.nabble.com/shorten-and-decoration-td2248.html, and seems it still applies. Hence, you need to say `squiggly={pre length=10pt, post length=10pt}` in addition to the shortens.

[image: output of code with shortened arrow]

```
\documentclass[border-5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \bullet && \bullet
    \arrow[shorten <=10pt, shorten >=10pt,
            squiggly={
               pre length=10pt, post length=10pt
             },
             from=1-1, to=1-3]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The amplitude/contraction of your squiggly is different of the first image. Is it possible to change?+1 for you excellent work.

Comment: @Sebastiano The code I added didn't change anything about the amplitude and wavelength. But yes, you can change those things if you want to, add e.g. `segment length=2mm, amplitude=2mm` in the argument to `squiggly`, along with `pre length` and `post length`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the addition of explanation.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility could be replace the `shorten`s by `start anchor` and `end anchor`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \bullet && \bullet
    \arrow[squiggly, start anchor={[xshift=10pt]}, end anchor={[xshift=-10pt]}, from=1-1, to=1-3]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very good. +1 for your code.

Comment: Thanks, although it would be nice not to have to change `shorten` key as in Torbjørn T answer

Comment: Thanks, this is a simple solution for vertical or horizontal arrows, though becomes a little trickier with diagonals where the offset has to be calculated manually.